# Build a RESTful Web service using Jersey and Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jersey-client

I am new to java web-service programming and setup. my requirement is just need to host a simple rest web-server and that can be called by post or get method and also that can capture the json response from post method to string variable.

there i have created basic dynamic project this simple code giving me 404 error on where i should get the xml respond.

can anyone tell me what should be the code and setup to meet my desire requirement.

browser on http://localhost:9090/WSdemo/book URL

[image: project]

[image: book.java]

[image: web.xml]

Comment: Why `<param-value>$package</param-value>`. That value should be the name of the package you want Jersey to scan to find all your `@Path` classes and register them.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a link that i used when i was working with jersey.
[Comphrensive jersey guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#firstjersey)

But..

If you want to host a simple rest service you should really take a look at spring-boot.

https://spring.io/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

i just started working with spring myself and it is an ease!

Comment: i agree but unfortunately I am not able to do that yet.